# Socket Io Error Failed to load resources and get 404 not found

Tags: reactjs, web, next.js, socket.io, vercel

Hello So I created this chat app on socket.io in next js 14 and it works completedly fine when I host it on localhost but hosting it on vercel gives this error in the console

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()/socket.io?EIO=4&t=Onyyxp1.0&transport=polling:1

And following that it gives GET https://chat-akshat1706.vercel.app/socket.io?EIO=4&t=Onyz9kC&transport=polling 404 (Not Found)

The url to my website is - https://chat-akshat1706.vercel.app/(Please dont look at the design )

This below is my server.js file

```
const http = require("http");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const cors = require("cors");

const httpServer = http.createServer();

const io = new Server(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: "https://chat-akshat1706.vercel.app", // Replace with your frontend URL
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    allowedHeaders: ["my-custom-header"],
    credentials: true,
  },
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("A user connected:", socket.id);
  socket.on("join_room", (roomId) => {
    socket.join(roomId);
    console.log(`user with id-${socket.id} joined room - ${roomId}`);
  });

  socket.on("send_msg", (data) => {
    console.log(data, "DATA");
    //This will send a message to a specific room ID
    socket.to(data.roomId).emit("receive_msg", data);
  });

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("A user disconnected:", socket.id);
  });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
httpServer.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Socket.io server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

This is my page.tsx

```
"use client";
import styles from "./page.module.css";
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
import { useState } from "react";
import ChatPage from "./chat/page";

export default function Home() {
  const [showChat, setShowChat] = useState(false);
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState("");
  const [showSpinner, setShowSpinner] = useState(false);
  const [roomId, setroomId] = useState("");

  var socket: any;
  socket = io("https://chat-akshat1706.vercel.app/");

  const handleJoin = () => {
    if (userName !== "" && roomId !== "") {
      console.log(userName, "userName", roomId, "roomId");
      socket.emit("join_room", roomId);
      setShowSpinner(true);
// You can remove this setTimeout and add your own logic
      setTimeout(() => {
        setShowChat(true);
        setShowSpinner(false);
      }, 4000);
    } else {
      alert("Please fill in Username and Room Id");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className={styles.heading}>Chatroom</h1>
      <div
        className={styles.main_div}
        style={{ display: showChat ? "none" : "" }}
      >
        <input
          className={styles.main_input}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Username"
          onChange={(e) => setUserName(e.target.value)}
          disabled={showSpinner}
        />
        <input
          className={styles.main_input}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Room Id"
          onChange={(e) => setroomId(e.target.value)}
          disabled={showSpinner}
        />
        <button className={styles.main_button} onClick={() => handleJoin()}>
          {!showSpinner ? (
            "Join"
          ) : (
            <div className={styles.loading_spinner}></div>
          )}
        </button>
      </div>
      <div style={{ display: !showChat ? "none" : "" }}>
        <ChatPage socket={socket} roomId={roomId} username={userName} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And then inside the chat folder I have another page.tsx here

```
"use client"
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import style from "./chat.module.css";

interface IMsgDataTypes {
  roomId: String | number;
  user: String;
  msg: String;
  time: String;
}

const ChatPage = ({ socket, username, roomId }: any) => {
  const [currentMsg, setCurrentMsg] = useState("");
  const [chat, setChat] = useState<IMsgDataTypes[]>([]);

  const sendData = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (currentMsg !== "") {
      const msgData: IMsgDataTypes = {
        roomId,
        user: username,
        msg: currentMsg,
        time:
          new Date(Date.now()).getHours() +
          ":" +
          new Date(Date.now()).getMinutes(),
      };
      await socket.emit("send_msg", msgData);
      setCurrentMsg("");
    }
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("receive_msg", (data: IMsgDataTypes) => {
      setChat((pre) => [...pre, data]);
    });
  }, [socket]);


  return (
    <div className={style.chat_div}>
      <div className={style.chat_border}>
        <div style={{ marginBottom: "1rem" }}>
          <p>
            Name: <b>{username}</b> and Room Id: <b>{roomId}</b>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div>
          {chat.map(({ roomId, user, msg, time }, key) => (
            <div
              key={key}
              className={
                user == username
                  ? style.chatProfileRight
                  : style.chatProfileLeft
              }
            >
              <span
                className={style.chatProfileSpan}
                style={{ textAlign: user == username ? "right" : "left" }}
              >
                {user.charAt(0)}
              </span>
              <h3 style={{ textAlign: user == username ? "right" : "left" }}>
                {msg}
              </h3>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={(e) => sendData(e)}>
            <input
              className={style.chat_input}
              type="text"
              value={currentMsg}
              placeholder="Type your message.."
              onChange={(e) => setCurrentMsg(e.target.value)}
            />
            <button className={style.chat_button}>Send</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ChatPage;
```

This is my folder structure
[The root of my folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMXbE.png)

Below is the link to my github repo if any additional details are required
https://github.com/Akshat1706/Chat/tree/main

Its possible that I have deployed the entire website wrong if that is the case please tell me the correct way to deploy a socket js website

Thank you for giving this your time